# How to read JSON file inside CodeIgniter Controller

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I can't read my json file inside codeigniter controller, it returns an error.

My code:

```
$curYear = date("Y");
$string = file_get_contents(base_url("assets/data/".$curYear."_cal.json"));
```

Error Message return by my controller trying to read json file using:

> file_get_contents(//localhost/EBR_Labeling/assets/data/2018_cal.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

---

## Solved

Using this syntax:

```
file_get_contents("./assets/data/".$curYear."_cal.json")
```

Comment: You should include the error message as text, not screenshot. It says **"no such file or directory"**. → What do *you* make of that error message and the mentioned location? Why apply `base_url()` to the path? (Btw, it's no longer necessary to mention being new or pleading for help.)

Comment: Ok I will update the description, Why apply base_url to the path? my assets/data folder is outside from my application folder, and I think that is the only way to get the full path of my json file

Comment: Check if this URL is returning the data: http://localhost/EBR_Labeling/assets/data/2018_cal.json

Comment: Yes, when I manually access that file, it returns the content of my json file

Comment: You'll need to find the real (filesystem) path to your assets folder. Using `//localhost/…`  is not the proper syntax (neither a path nor URL, and you shouldn't triggger a http subrequest in any case).

Comment: Dear, please check `file_get_contents("http://localhost/EBR_Labeling/assets/data/2018_cal.json");` @mario: the localhost link is generated by base_url function. I believe he didn't use it himself.

Comment: Oh yes, I remember the code that I used on my last project, I'm using this syntax for dir outside the application dir ("./assets/data/".$curYear."_cal.json"), Thank Mario and Yamin

Comment: If resolved please add your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Please use this code --**

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents(FILE_PATH);
$obj  = json_decode($json);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($obj) . '</pre>';

?>
```

And let me know If you need any other help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can simply store all json in views folder and can access it directly as follow:-

```
<?php 
    $countries = $this->load->view('countries.json', '', true) //this will load countries.json
    $countries = json_decode($countries);
?>
```

**Points to be noted : -**

1. `$this->load->view('countries')` is same as writing `$this->load->view('countries.php')`
   And this loads the view in browser and doesn't store it in variable. When we want some another type of file to be loaded, then we can simply change the extension.
2. `$this->load->view('countries', $data, true);`
   Passing third parameter as **true** allows us to **store the view** in **variable**. If we don't want to pass second parameter then we can pass empty string as `$this->load->view('countries', '', true);`